# Why do I always obtain historical information using wifiManager.getConnectionInfo()?

Tags: android, wifimanager

I confirm that ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission is enabled, and my app TargetSdkVersion is 30.

I switched from Wi-Fi A to another Wi-Fi B and the Wi-Fi B connection was successful. But the info.getssid of wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() is always Wi-Fi A information. When I kill app
and reopen it, wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() does right and return Wi-Fi B info.

Please help me Why wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() does not as expected? And How to solve it?

I registered for `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast, and then I got network info :

```
Parcelable parcelableExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
if (parcelableExtra instanceof NetworkInfo) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) parcelableExtra;
    NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState();
    if (state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        if (isSameNetwork()) {
            // do something..
        }
    }
}
```

```
public boolean isSameNetwork() {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)host.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (info != null) {
        String ssid = info.getSSID();
        if (ssid != null && TextUtils.equals(ssid, myssid)) {
            // do something..
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to determine if current connection is it as I expected.

I would like to determine if the current Wi Fi connection is my expected Wi Fi